# If statement for datatables configuration

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm working with the jQuery Datatables plugin for my table and I'm trying to figure out how I can have a td cell that has a class of nosortable that is contained inside a tr that is in the thead tag not contain padding right as is default with the use of the datatables configuration.

I would assume that I would need an IF statement to work with for this but not sure how to incorporate this into my project.

```
<thead class="">
    <tr>
        <th class="nosortable center"><input type="checkbox" id="selectall" /></th>
        <th class="center">ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email Address</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th class="nosortable center">Actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#basicTable').DataTable({ 
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ "nosortable" ] }
        ],
        "order": []
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xtremer360/unpx282m/

Comment: Can you show your javascript code?

Comment: Sure I'll create a jsfiddle for this.

Comment: I included the fiddle for viewing.